Prove that for $f$ a Lipschitz function on $\mathbb{R}^d$, $\overline{\mu}(A) := \int|f^{-1}(y) \cap A|dy$ extends to a Radon measure
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be an $l$-Lipschitz function, and let $\mathcal{L}$ be the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$. We may verify that the function $y \mapsto |f^{-1}(y) \cap A|$ (i.e. the cardinality of the set $f^{-1}(y) \cap A$) is a $\mathcal{L}$-measurable function (this is given). Let
$$\overline{\mu}(A) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f^{-1}(y) \cap A| dy.$$
Show that $\overline{\mu}$ can be extended to an outer measure $\mu$ which is a Radon measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Show that every $\mathcal{L}$-measurable set is $\mu$-measurable.
Here is my work so far:
Let $\mu : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d) \to [0, \infty]$ be defined by
$$\mu(A) := \inf \{ \overline{\mu}(C) : A \subseteq C \textrm{, $C$ is $\mathcal{L}$-measurable} \}$$.
I have shown that $\mu$ extends $\overline{\mu}$ and that $\mu$ is an outer measure. I have also shown that $\mu(K)$ is finite for all compact $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$.
However, I was having hard time proving that $\mu$ is outer regular for all borel sets $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ and that it is inner regular for all open sets $O \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$.
Let $\mu'(B) := \inf \{ \mu(U) : A \subseteq U \textrm{, $U$ is open } \}$. We want to show that $\mu(B) = \mu'(B)$. For any $B \subseteq U$ with $U$ open, we have $\mu(B) \leq \mu(U) = \overline{\mu}(U)$. Since $U$ was arbitrary open set containing $B$, it follows that $\mu(B) \leq \mu'(B)$. How do I show the other direction? I tried using the fact that $B = \bigcap O_i - N$ for some open sets $O_i$ and a Lebesgue null set $N$, but I couldn't get anywhere. Similarly, if I let, for any open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$, $\mu''(U) := \sup \{ \mu(K) : K \subseteq U \textrm{, $K$ is compact} \}$, then I can get $\mu''(U) \leq \mu(U)$, but I couldn't get the other direction.
How do I also show that every Lebesgue measurable set is $\mu$-measurable?
